# MongoError: Connection Closed By Application in MongoDB driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

While running the following code in NodeJS I am getting the error **MongoError: Connection Closed By Application.** I tried to resolve it but unable all the time. I need somebody's help...

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/weather', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var data = db.collection('data');
    var options = { 'sort' : [['State', 1], ['Temperature', -1]] };
    var cursor = data.find({}, {}, options);

    var firstState = '';
    var currentState='';
    var previousState='';
    var previousRecord='';

    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(doc == null) {
            return db.close();
        }

        currentState= doc['State'];
        previousState = previousRecord['State'];

        if(previousState === undefined) {           
            console.dir(currentState);
            firstState= doc['State'];

            db.collection('data').update({'_id' : doc['_id']}, {$set :{'month_high' : true}}, {'upsert' : true}, function(err, upserted){
                if(err) throw err;

                console.dir("Successfully upserted "+upserted + " document!");
            });

        } else if(currentState !=previousState){
                if (firstState!=currentState){                
                    console.dir(previousState);

                db.collection('data').update({'_id' : previousRecord['_id']}, {$set :{'month_high' : true}}, {'upsert' : true}, function(err, upserted){
                if(err) throw err;               

                console.dir("Successfully upserted "+upserted + " document!");
            });

                }
            }        

        previousRecord = doc;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the application implementing **[node stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html)** interface which finally resolved the issue of **"MongoError: Connection Closed By Application"**.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/weather', function(err, db) {   
     if(err) throw err;
     var data = db.collection('data');
     var options = { 'sort' : [['State', 1], ['Temperature', -1]] };
     var cursor = data.find({}, {}, options);

     var previousState='';  

    cursor.on("end", function(){
        db.close();
    });

    cursor.on("err", function(){
        console.dir("Error on:" + err);
        throw err;
    });

cursor.on("data", function(doc){
    cursor.pause();
    if(previousState != doc.State){
        previousState = doc.State;
        var query = { _id: doc._id};
        var operator = {$set: {month_high: true}};

        db.collection('data').update(query, operator, {'upsert' : true}, function(err, upserted){
          if(err){
                console.dir('Error : '+ err);
                throw err;
            } 
            console.dir("Successfully upserted "+ upserted + " document!");
            cursor.resume();
        });
    } else{
            cursor.resume();
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

This is asynchronous code with asynchronous calls to the database, however the `.each()` iterator being used here does not wait for the contained callbacks to complete.

This is the primary cause of the error here, as the processing has not actually completed by the time the `db.close()` is being called. So this is what needs to be fixed.

Whilst a general clean-up of your code was certainly in order, the main things here are replacing that loop with [stream processing](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), and also avoiding the "repeat yourself" calls to "update" by just altering the conditions and keeping the flow control in one place:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/weather', function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;

  var data = db.collection('data');
  var options = { 'sort' : [['State', 1], ['Temperature', -1]] };
  var cursor = data.find({}, {}, options);

  var firstState = '',
    currentState='',
    previousState='',
    previousRecord='';


  cursor.on("end",function() {
    db.close();
  });

  cursor.on("err",function(err) {
    throw err;
  });

  cursor.on("data",function(data){
    cursor.pause();            // Stops events emitting on stream
    currentState = doc.State;
    previousState = previousRecord.State;

    var query =  { "_id": null };

    if (previousState === undefined) {           
      console.dir(currentState);
      firstState= doc.State;
      query._id  = doc._id;
    } else if(currentState != previousState) {
      if (firstState != currentState) {
        console.dir(previousState);
        query._id = previousRecord._id;
      }
    }        

    if (query._id != null) {
      db.collection('data').update(
        query, 
        { "$set":{ "month_high": true } },
        { "upsert": true },
        function(err, upserted){
          if(err) throw err;

          console.dir("Successfully upserted "+upserted + " document!");
          cursor.resume();     // resumes events on stream
          previousRecord = doc;

      });
    } else {
      cursor.resume();         // resumes events on stream
      previousRecord = doc;
    }

  });
});
```

The `.pause()` and `.resume()` methods there make sure that no new data is emitted in the stream until the current processing is done for the current document retrieved. This keeps your external variables in check.

Note that `.resume()` is also called "within" the callback to the `.update()` as you don't want to continue until this is returned as completed.

Comment: I would like to say thank you very much for your valuable time and help but I am getting error while running the program you gave me. Can you please test it there and repost it again. There might be some parenthesis or some other problem. I tried to figure it out myself but couldn't due to lack of knowledge in stream processing. I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @DPBhatt What error? I have not really done anything here other than cut and paste bits of your code into the correct sections and removed any code duplication. So I'm not writng your program, just showing you how to structure correctly and respect waiting for callbacks to complete. Any errors are the fault of your own implemented logic. Which I have not really changed.

Comment: "@Blakes Seven" I would like to say thank you for the stream concept which I was completely unaware in Nodejs. I rewrote the program to correct some logic which was incorrect in my side. There was another problem at callback function  cursor.on("data",function(data){. You used here data but in the program referring as doc.State which is minor thing. I noticed it while rewriting the program. I corrected my logic also. I am posting the correct logic also. Thank you very much once again for the help which was really a lot.